# Matplotlib & Jupyter - Same command returns different results in different cells

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

First Jupyter cell:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
%matplotlib notebook

plt.figure()
plt.plot((1,2,3))

labels = [item.get_text() for item in plt.gca().get_xticklabels()]
print("Labels are: {}".format(labels))
```

The ouput is (besides the chart):

Labels are: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

Now, in another cell, if I run the same code:

```
labels = [item.get_text() for item in plt.gca().get_xticklabels()]
print("Labels are: {}".format(labels))
```

The ouput is:

Labels are: ['', '0.00', '0.25', '0.50', '0.75', '1.00', '1.25', '1.50', '1.75', '2.00', '']

Why the same code, referencing the same Axes, returns different results?

Comment: Probably the `plt` object has changed when the plot is rendered. Some internal magic in matplotlib, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, Haken, but it's not that. I checked the Axes ID with id(plt.gca()) and it is the same in both cells.

Comment: I was thinking about the internal state of the object. Matplotlib has many quirks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interesting problem, as far as I can tell it seems to be that while you are referencing the same object in both lots of code the actual *plotting* that jupyter is doing isn't side-effect free.

The plot itself is generated when the code in the cell has finished running (at least with the notebook back-end), and during the generation the details such as the xtick-labels are populated. Naïvely I assume that this is because you can add additional things to the plots that will change the *x* and *y* limits of the figure and it's more efficient to only do that once when we need to see it.

Note that you can *manually* set the xtick-labels prior to the generation of the plot if you know what they are going to be (or what you want them to be) ahead of time:

```
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(list_of_labels)
```

However, if you do actually need the label values prior to the plot being generated you can always use

```
plt.gca().get_xticks()
```

This will return a list of the locations of the ticks and from there it's pretty easy to make the labels from that

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
%matplotlib notebook

# generate the figure and axes objects
plt.figure()
plt.plot((1, 2, 3))  # plot the data

# now we can look at the xtick positions, and infer the labels
labels = ["{:.2f}".format(item) for item in plt.gca().get_xticks()]
print("Labels are: {}".format(labels))
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

Use:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: I actually want to use the nbAgg backend (%matplotlib notebook) to refer to the same figure.